# S3 Cross account setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have two accounts in AWS like Account A and Account B. In Account A whenever I upload objects in S3 bucket it should load automatically into Account B, S3 bucket. Can anyone suggest me how to write Lambda function using python for this and which IAM role we can use for this.?

Comment: https://medium.com/@markgituma/copy-s3-bucket-objects-across-separate-aws-accounts-programmatically-323862d857ed

Comment: http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-mirror-s3-buckets/

Comment: Could you please clarify your situation? Are you saying that you have an AWS Lambda function in Account-A that should upload content to an Amazon S3 bucket that is owned by Account-B?

Comment: No John, I don't have  Lambda function with me. I have to write lambda function for this above scenario.    I want to load s3 bucket object automatically from one account to other account. for this I want to write lambda function.

Comment: Have you considered using [Amazon S3 Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html) to automatically copy the objects to another bucket, or is there a particular reason why you wish to use an AWS Lambda function?

Comment: one of my project having this requirement. like we have to data from redshift to s3 using amazon glue and ETL job later our main data lake is in different account so that again we have to move data from this account s3 to other account s3 data lake.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is:

- Create an **AWS Lambda function** in `Account-A`
- The Lambda function should be able to **create Amazon S3 objects** in a bucket (`Bucket-B`) owned by `Account-B`

The simplest setup for this would be:

- Create an **IAM Role** for the Lambda function
- The role should have permission to `PutObject` in `Bucket-B` (or even any bucket), such as:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

- On `Bucket-B` (in `Account-B`), add a Bucket Policy that permits the above IAM Role to write to the bucket:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-B>:role/lambda-role",
      "Action":["s3:PutObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

- When writing objects to `Bucket-B`, make sure the Lambda function sets `ACL='bucket-owner-full-control'` so that ownership is transferred to `Account-B`

The above method does not require assuming a role in `Account-B`, because the bucket policy on `Bucket-B` permits access via the IAM Role from `Account-A`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please brief me about the Lambda function and IAM role.

Comment: @Ratkal-Guru Sorry, I do not understand what you are asking. What do you mean by "brief me about the Lambda function and IAM role"?

Comment: Hi John, I need Lambda function. can you show me how to write lambda function for this above scenario.